# Graph Api - Send Message to Channel Failed with Error "Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes"

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use the Graph Api to send the message to a channel in Microsoft Teams by following the guidance for this link [text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)
However i am getting the below error:
Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details.

Below is my code:

```
string clientId = "**";
string clientSecret = "**";
string tenantId = "**";

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
   AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

 var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new ChatMessage
    {
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            Content = "Hello World",
        },
    };

string teamId = "**";
string channelId = "**";
var result = await graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Messages.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

[Api Permission Granted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzvG5.png)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#:%7E:text=permissions%20going%20forward.-,Note%3A,-Application%20permissions%20are), sending messages in teams channels with application permission are only supported for migration. So, it seems to me that it's not possible to send teams message with application permissions at all.

Comment: what i am doing now is not for migration purpose. The thing that i want to achieve is able to send a message to the channel with my program. Is there any other way i can try?

Comment: @LeeYiHao I've checked the doc and it seems to be not possible with application permissions.